# Unwanted space under img in div using mPDF

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I am using mPDF to create a PDF from the following HTML-Code:

```
<div style="border: 5px solid black; height: 115px;">
    <div style="width: 29%; height: 115px; float: left; background-color: red;">
        <img src="testimage.png"
             alt="Bild 1" style="height: 115px;">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 55%; float: left; padding-top: 60px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 16%; font-size: 18px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 25px;">ANOTHER TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outcome in the PDF is rather unsatisfying:
[The outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGhnE.png)

I am dealing with this weird space below the image. I tried giving the image a blue and the div a red background and it is always red, so the div is too high. It just ignores every fixed height I give. I already read about using `display: top` but none of it worked. What exactly is the problem here? On a HTML-Page everything is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width:100%;` `height:100%;` `object-fit:cover;` to the image. Hope it works for you.

```html
<div style="border: 5px solid black; height: 115px;">
    <div style="width: 29%; height: 115px; float: left; background-color: red;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
             alt="Bild 1" style="width:100%; 
                height:100%; 
                object-fit:cover;">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 55%; float: left; padding-top: 60px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 16%; font-size: 18px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 25px;">ANOTHER TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly that didn't do the trick. The image is just a square now yet the space below is still present. If I take the img out of the div, the space is absent but now the floats won't work properly

Comment: Have you tried giving the second `div` a fixed width too?  Also, the code in your question didn't work fine in html.